# Macro Recording to define cell name

Tags: vba, excel

I have recorded a macro with relative reference on, where the first cell is the name I want to give the range so I select the range I want to name -> right click -> define name -> since the name is already included in the first cell I don't need to change anything so -> I click OK.

```
Example
A1:B5 - I want to name it TSLA56
then I go to D1 to run the recorded macro to name D1:E5 to TSLA23
```

After the macro is done running it is still called D1

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Record Macro:

```
Sub DefineName()
'
' DefineName Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:B5").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="TSLA56", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R1C1:R5C2"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("TSLA56").Comment = ""
End Sub
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFVIN.png): [image]

Comment: you are naming D1:E5,so the name will not show in the cell reference until the entire range is selected. You can also check name manager to see the definitions that have been created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your actions are being recorded as *relative* wherever possible some things like the `Name:=` and `.RefersTo:=`  when defining a name are not made relative. You can adjust this by editing and passing the selections address into the macro code line.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=selection.cells(1,1).value, refersTo:="=" & selection.address
```

`selection.cells(1,1).value` refers to the value in the top-left cell of any single or multiple cell selection.